# Adding extra headers in sonarqube webhook

Tags: node.js, authentication, sonarqube

In our node application, we are using `sonarqube-scanner` package. To connect to the sonarqube instance, we were giving 2 parameters in `serverUrl` and `token`

```
(async function() {
await config.initEnvironmentVariables();

sonarqubeScanner({
    serverUrl: nodecache.getValue('SONARQUBE_URL'),
    token: nodecache.getValue('SONARQUBE_TOKEN'),
    options: {
        'sonar.sources': 'src/modules',
        'sonar.tests': 'tests',
        'sonar.inclusions': '**',
        'sonar.test.inclusions': 'tests/**/*.spec.js',
        'sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths': 'coverage/lcov.info',
        'sonar.testExecutionReportPaths': 'coverage/test-report.xml'
    }
}, () => process.exit());
})();
```

The problem now is, we have our sonarqube instance under custom authentication. Meaning first we have to log in, then we see the sonarqube login page, then when we log in to sonarqube, we can see the sonarqube reports.

Using serverUrl and token we can authenticate sonarqube instance. But to get through custom auth on top of it, we need to provide extra headers.

**My question is: If we can, How we can we add extra headers to the request that authenticates with sonarqube instance.**

[image: Image here]

Ok.

Comment: I am afraid this is currently not [supported](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/secure-sonarqube-instance-with-cloudflare-access/88234). I am trying to figure out a way to a) run the scan using `sonar-scanner` cli b) skip posting the results to the SQ instance c) use `curl` to post the results passing my custom headers. If you have any progress on this do share it pls